# Combine Coverflow and Universal Image Loader libs

Tags: android, universal-image-loader, coverflow

I like to use these two libs. [Coverflow](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html) creates carousel and [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#user-support) loads and set to ImageViews images from Web.
The issue is I want to load Images from UIL and pass them to Coverflow.

Is it possible? Does anybody has such practice?

Comment: hey i implement it but now i have problem in vm budget outof memory so how can i solve it

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with this. I've catched some OOM exception with UIL too. Maybe you should ask new question here.

Comment: but now i create another coverflow with memory exception and is work fine

Comment: @dimetil did you find any solution ? Here is my Question can you help me ?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30547838/not-showing-cache-or-downloaded-images-in-fancycoverflow